# MacBook Air Backlit Keys Not Adjusting

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, display

I have the `Adjust keyboard brightness in low light` option selected but this just isn't working correctly.

The screen brightness adjust automatically (i.e. I put my thumb over the webcam and the screen dims, I point a light at the webcam and the screen brightness increases), but the keyboard either does nothing, OR only turns on when in bright rooms. When I turn off all the lights the keys go off.

Is there any way to adjust this and make it work properly?

Comment: i had a similar problem, and the only fix i had was to backup and reinstall the OS

Comment: Now your keys work correctly? I've never seen it work right on any MacBook.